# fopen_s issue in visual studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm doing an assignment for C++ in Visual Studio 2015 and I keep getting a `stream != nulltpr` error or a `stream.valid()` error when trying to open a file to read a value. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

FILE *data;

int main(void)
{
    errno_t err;

    err = fopen_s(&data, "input.txt", "r");                                     

    if (err == 0) {                                                                  
        printf_s("the file was opened");                                    
    }
    else {
        printf_s("error, input file not opened\n"); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: stated errors do not match the given code at all. Also this is more like a C code

Comment: I am definitely running C++ on visual studio 2015. How would i fix this?

Comment: You mention a `stream != nulltpr` error - but I can't see `stream` anywhere. Also, where do you run this? Is there a file called "input.txt" in the working directory?

Comment: No i do not have stream anywhere in this code which is why this error has me dumbfounded. Yes there is a file called "input.txt" in the working directory

Comment: I suspect that this is not a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is there are `read` calls later that get executed even though shown error check failed and `data` is NULL.

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? How are you running the code? Step back and write a "Hello, World!" program and check that works. Do you just have one project in your solution? Is that the start up project?

Comment: The first argument to fopen_s is the stream. Maybe there is a check that data is null before it overwrites it with the new pointer. Try "FILE *data = nullptr;" to initialise it before using it.

Comment: okay, would i need to add more in, or just that line?

Comment: Just change that line first and see if it helps at all...